# How do I make Heroku use node 14.x instead of 12.x?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I need Heroku to use NodeJS 14 instead of 12, how do I do that? On my computer I'm using Node 14, and I'm defining it in engines on `package.json` (at the root of my repo):

```
{
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.x"
  }
  ...
}
```

I have both the `heorku/nodejs` as well as the `heroku/rails` buildpack installed because this is a Ruby on Rails apps with webpack:

[image]

But when running my tests is Heroku, I get this error:

```
Error: Missing binding /app/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-72/binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Node.js 12.x
Found bindings for the following environments:
  - Linux 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (88)
```

If I workaround the problem in the CI, I still run into trouble when deploying:

```
-----> Installing node-v12.16.2-linux-x64
-----> Installing yarn-v1.22.4
-----> Detecting rake tasks
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       yarn install v1.22.4
       [1/5] Validating package.json...
       error imok@0.1.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "14.x". Got "12.16.2"
       error Found incompatible module.
       info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: Hi, just to be sure, can you display the result of `heroku buildpacks` command ?

Comment: is it possible u may need multiple buildpacks ( node && rails )  : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app

Comment: @VictorBls I don't have the heroku cli installed, if you are after the list of buildpacks, I have heroku/ruby and heroku/nodejs. I'll add the details to the question.

Comment: @RobertRowntree: yes, I need and I have multiple buildpacks, heroku/ruby and heroku/nodejs. It's at the end of my question. I'll clarify.

Comment: Well everything is clear in your buildpack and the `engines` definition, maybe your `package.json` isn't at the root of your connected repository ? @pupeno

Comment: @VictorBls: it is, it's just a plain standard Ruby on Rails app, it places `packages.json` at the root.

Comment: Ok last chance : try to update your buildpack position (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app#adding-a-buildpack) by moving `heroku/nodejs` at the first position of execution and `heroku/ruby` at the 2nd ?

Comment: The problem was the order in which the buildpacks were added. Glen found the solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In [the documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app) it says:

> If you need a specific version of node for your Ruby application you should use multiple buildpacks to first install node then install Ruby.

which means if you deployed a Rails application, you need to remove all buildpacks and then re-add them in the correct order, first `heroku/node` and then `heroku/rails`.

Comment: I have no idea why a working build stopped working but this certainly fixed the issue. Much appreciated.